# database error while saveOrUpdate using Spring 3 Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3, hibernate etc.  I am trying to update a counter col in my table.. I do a select of the row, copy the data from the row to a new object and then try to do a saveOrUpdate with the new object and I get the following error:

My source code:

```
public void updateSerialNumber(SerialNumber sn) {
        SerialNumber MySN = new SerialNumber();
        log.debug("sn:" + sn.toString());
        MySN.setName(sn.getName());
        MySN.setValue(sn.getValue());
        MySN.setSerialNumberId(sn.getSerialNumberId());
        log.debug("MySN:" + MySN.toString());
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(MySN);              
}
```

My Error:

```
2012-07-25 13:46:30,725 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [org.uftwf.model.SerialNumber#CERT]
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:590)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to update the counter why are you copying the Object? You cannot have two different objects with the same id (@Id in your Entity) assosiated with the hibernate session. I guess you're using one of the properties you are setting on `MySN` as the ID. I'd suggest using a surrogate ID (and afaik this is als what is recommended in hibernate documentation) which can be e.g. assigned by a db-sequence (if you're using oracle DB) and if you have to copy the object just leave this surrogate id `null` and you'll be able to save it.

Comment: I agree with you, but I am concerned that since he is using a saveorUpdate, that problem shoudl not occur. dear op, you might want to post your hibernate mapping file